# How can I separate a string of urls and print each link?

Tags: php, string

How can I separate each link from my string:

```
$field = "www.link1.com
www.link2.com";
```

And output them like this (expected output):

```
link1 title
www.link1.com
link2 title
www.link2.com
```

My current code looks like this:

```
<?php

    $field = 
    "www.link1.com
    www.link2.com";

    if ($field == "link1");
    {
        $output="link1 title</br>".$field ;   
    }  
    echo $output;

?>
```

But it only outputs this (current output):

```
link1 title
www.link1.com www.link2.com
```

So how can I change/modify my code to get the urls separated and print them like  shown above?

Comment: Your if statement does nothing even if it is true, since you have a semicolon at the end

Comment: or maybe i need the help of MySQL ? w/c find Where="link1" or I only need the php about this?

Comment: it will best if you do it at sql level. thanks.

Comment: @Rizier123 what do u mean? im sorry im lost.

Comment: your `if` have `;`. he is talking about to remove it.

Comment: why does $field = 
"www.link1.com
www.link2.com"; ? I think you want an array?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want. But do you just want to explode it into an array, like this: `$arr = array_map("trim", explode(PHP_EOL, $field));
  
  foreach($arr as $v) {
   echo $v . " title<br>";
   echo preg_replace("/^www\.([^\.]*)(.*?)$/", "$1", $v) . "<br><br>";
  }` ?

Comment: the $field is where I put the links..then automatically do what i wanted.. but if I use array with that field how can I seperate them?

Comment: It's so unclear what you want. I have no idea. (^ So the pasted code above isn't what you want?)

Comment: @Rizier123 I tried it it works how I wanted it.. thank you I'll study it.
Sorry I didn't saw ur comment before posting the last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first `explode()` your string into an array, so that we have each url as array element.

Then we just loop through each link and print them. We also grab the name between `www.` and the next dot with `preg_replace()`.

```
$arr = array_map("trim", explode(PHP_EOL, $field));

foreach($arr as $v) {
    echo $v . " title<br>";
    echo preg_replace("/^www\.([^\.]*)(.*?)$/", "$1", $v) . "<br><br>";
}
```